# I need to match a certain part of url path using Regex and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have the following link:

sitename.com/Default.aspx?PageID=13078494

I want to grab the following: "PageID=13078494". This is what I have so far:

```
var url = "sitename.com/Default.aspx?PageID=13078494";    
urlmatch = url.match([PageID=13078494]);
urlmatch[0];
```

Is this the proper expression for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Just to check, are you trying to match any page ID, or specifically the page ID 13078494? From your example it's difficult to tell. We're all assuming (myself included) you meant that you want to match any page id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex and its syntax are wrong.

A better way would be to not use a regex at all. Use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead:

```
var urlmatch = url.split('?')[1];
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qpXNU/

Answer (score 2):

```
var myregexp = /[?&]PageID=(\d+)/i;
var match = myregexp.exec(url);
if (match != null) {
    //This is if your match it successful
    result = match[1];
} else {
    //This is if url doesn't match
    result = "";
}
```

This one will work regardless of where PageID is. It will match

- sitename.com/Default.aspx?PageID=13078494
- anything.org/Default.aspx?PageID=13078494
- sitename.com/Default.aspx?foo=bar&PageID=13078494
- sitename.com/Default.html?foo=bar&PageID=13078494&bar=foo
- Default.html?foo=bar&PageID=13078494&bar=foo

Importantly, it WON'T match

- sitename.com/Default.aspx?NotThePageID=13078494

Or without the checking, simply
`url.match(/[?&]PageID=(\d+)/i)[1]`, but I'd advice against that unless your SURE it will always match.

Comment: +1 Good catch on `?$` - not sure what I was smoking to have missed that. One small problem: `[?|&]` matches `|` as well, since `[]` denotes a list of characters to match, unlike `()` where a pipe acts as an `or` separator.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the catch. Originally these were round braces and I made them square braces and forgot to remove the OR operator. ;)

Comment: Easily done - don't forget to change it in your second example too! Also just noticed you're grabbing `match[0]`, which will contain the full matched text (`PageID=13078494`) - the first capture group ends up in `match[1]` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex, which will extract the PageID and place it in the first match group:

```
var url = "sitename.com/Default.aspx?PageID=13078494";
urlmatch = url.match(/PageID=(\d+)/);
alert(urlmatch[1]);​ // 13078494
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are matching specific value, then it's fine, otherwise use below to match any number of digits in pageID:

```
      /PageID=\d+/
```

as:

```
    var url = "sitename.com/Default.aspx?PageID=13078494";
    var urlmatch = url.match(/PageID=\d+/);
    alert(urlmatch[0]);
```

or to match 8 exact digits in pageID, use:

```
      /PageID=\d{8}/
```

as:

```
    var url = "sitename.com/Default.aspx?PageID=13078494";
    var urlmatch = url.match(/PageID=\d{8}/);
    alert(urlmatch[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to handling URLs, the browser is pretty good.

You should convert your string to an actual URL like so:

```
var toURL = function (href) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = href;
    return a;
};
```

Now use the browser's [built-in parsing capabilities](http://www.w3.org/TR/url/#the-url-decomposition-idl-attributes):

```
var url = toURL('sitename.com/Default.aspx?PageID=13078494');
alert(url.search);
```