# Javascript regex for in between slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

In my current Javascript code I'm using:

```
.match(/[^/]+$/)
```

to get the final element of an url. For example, appltying it to:

```
/country/set/profile/yellow
```

would return me `yellow`. Now, I'm facing a problem, as I will need the element that always comes after `/country/`. for example, applying this new regex to:

```
/country/set/profile/yellow
```

would return me `set`. I've been trying a lot of things, but without any success. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: So, what have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Here is a great resource for constructing and understanding Regex expressions => https://regex101.com/

Comment: You know that you don't always need to use regex? Split at `/`, find the index of `country`, and `+1`.

Comment: Here is [a regex idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13337706/3832970). Adjust the pattern as required.

Comment: Why is that question downvoted so strongly? He said, he tried different *things, but without any success*. Should he say: ... *I tried `.*` but it didn't work*. that you downvoter guys are happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't even use a regex for that. You can split your URL and find the correct segment :

```js
let url = "some/stuff/here/country/set/profile/yellow",
    segments = url.split("/"),
    countryIndex = segments.indexOf("country"),
    word = segments[countryIndex + 1]
    
console.log(word) // "set"
```

Or in a more condensed form :

```js
let segments = "some/stuff/here/country/set/profile/yellow".split("/")
        
console.log( segments[ segments.indexOf("country") +1 ] ) // "set"
```